# How to plot a 3D surface with a circle in it?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a rational polynomial function. I find zeros of numerator and denominator of it. Now I want to draw this function and I do it with meshgrid and mesh command in matlab. How can I draw a circle in this shape? I add my result figure at first and second figure is an image that I want to be like that( draw red circle).

[image: my plot]

[image: plot that I want :(]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `x` and `y` for your circle:

```
r = 1;
theta = 0:0.1:2*pi;
x = r*cos(theta);
y = r*sin(theta);
```

Get the value of your function at the x and y's and plot a line in 3D with the values:

```
z = f(x,y);
plot3(x,y,z);
```

The final result may have some artefacts where the line crosses in and out of the surface. If you are not so concerned about the accuracy in the plot add a very small value to z to "lift" it above the surface.